# How to run application commands within a docker container? List logstash plugins

Tags: docker, plugins, logstash

Logstash is running in a docker container, and I'd like to list its plugins.

For a VM or metal installation, Here is the command [Ref 1]

```
sudo bin/plugin list
```

How do I run this command in a Docker container? I've tried the following, but no luck: [Ref 3]

```
sudo docker exec -it docker-elk_logstash_1 plugin list
sudo docker exec -it docker-elk_logstash_1 bin/plugin list
sudo docker exec -it docker-elk_logstash_1 /bin/plugin list
```

Nope.

**References**

1. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/listing-removing.html
2. http://phase2.github.io/devtools/common-tasks/ssh-into-a-container/
3. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was that the docs are outdated. It's now named ``logstash-plugin".

```
sudo docker exec -it docker-elk_logstash_1 bin/logstash-plugin list
```

Was successful.

I debugged it by shelling into the container, like so:

```
sudo docker exec -it docker-elk_logstash_1 bash
```

Sniffed around, and found `bin/logstash-plugin`. The following command successfully showed plugins:

```
bash-4.2$ pwd
/usr/share/logstash/bin
bash-4.2$ ./logstash-plugin list
```